# Generating a Random Account Number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, random

For privacy purposes, I need to derive an "Account Number" field that contains a random number, ranging from 1000 to 2000.

Comment: The RANDOM function is completely foreign to me and so I only tried RAND(), but it gives me a huge decimal number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```sql
SELECT (CONVERT(INT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)) % 1001) + 1000;
```

- `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)` returns a 2-byte randomized value. Range is 0x0000 - 0xFFFF (i.e. 0 - 65,535).
- `% 1001` caps the returned value at 1000 (since a returned value of 1001 resets back to 0). This handles / ensures the 1000 value range between the requested low-end of 1000 and high-end of 2000. (ok, technically 1001 values since we need to include the 0, but you know what I meant ;-)
- `+ 1000` adjusts the total range from being 0 - 1000 to instead be 1000 - 2000 (i.e. setting the lowest possible value)

Please note: [CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/crypt-gen-random-transact-sql) was introduced in SQL Server 2012, which is fine here as you are using 2016, but just for other readers to understand in case someone is using 2008 R2 or older (in which case you can still use the `RAND()` function as suggested by Scott).

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous examples on the Internet of generating random numbers between two numbers.

Here is an example function

```
--Random number function
CREATE FUNCTION Random (@Upper INT,@Lower INT, @randomvalue numeric(18,10))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Random INT
SELECT @Random = round(((@Upper - @Lower + 1 ) * @randomvalue + @Lower), 0, 1)
RETURN @Random
END;
go

--Test the function
select dbo.Random(2000,1000,RAND())
```

---

In response to one of the questions under this answer relating to why the `RAND()` function is being passed into the function, it's because `RAND()` cannot be used *inside* the function itself.  Trying to include `RAND()` inside the function will result in an error

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Random, Line 8 [Batch Start Line
>   2] Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

Comment: Nice job passing in the `RAND()` output.

Comment: If this is the easiest solution from all of the "numerous examples on the internet", then I'd really hate to see the most challenging solution.

Comment: @MikeJones - understood, I just picked a solution at 'random' ;)

Comment: @MikeJones To be fair, this is not very complicated. And, in many cases there is benefit to having it wrapped in a scalar function that you can call from many places. I think the only thing that would really be helped by some explanation is why the `RAND()` function is being passed in as a parameter to the function instead of being inside the function.